# Match element in list with possible values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I got a list of words. Let's say:

```
words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'g', 'h', 'v']
values = ['donkey', 'monkey', 'whale', 'dog']
```

Note: real lists are much longer

Depending on each element in the list `words` it should output a certain value.
For example, `a` should print `donkey`, b should print `whale` etcetera.

The `values` are very long(30 elements). Also they are handwritten. They aren't read from something else. The `words`are. This means I can choose for a dictionary or something else if this is better.
What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Why do you have repeated elements in `words`?

Comment: Why would `b` match `wale` (do you mean "whale?") and not `monkey`?

Comment: I updated my question. Sorry for the confusion @jpp

Comment: You're not really asking anything here. What is the criteria of deciding which word should be output?

Comment: @ninesalt actually I am. I need to match an element in words with a value in values

Comment: @keithpjolley yes I mean whale. About the matching. That's just how it shoud be. A should match donkey and b should match wale

Comment: @LakshayGarg the only criteria is that one element in words should match a certain value in values. You can make assumptions on which should match which

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should save it as a dictionary. Something  like this

```
lookup  =  {  'a': 'donkey', 'b':  'monkey', 'c':'wale'}
```

this will help  you access it  much better and  faster.

When you need `a` then  `lookup['a']` will give you the result.

Also your approach can be applied but the time complexity would be much  higher.

```
words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'g', 'h', 'v']
values = ['donkey', 'monkey', 'whale', 'dog']

print(values[words.index('b')])
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea how 'b' -> 'whale' in this scenario but...

```
In [5]: wv = dict(zip(words, values))

In [6]: wv
Out[6]: {'a': 'donkey', 'b': 'monkey', 'c': 'whale', 'd': 'dog'}

In [7]: wv['a']
Out[7]: 'donkey'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip to convert the lists to a dictionary

```
dict(zip(words, values))
```

zip will automatically truncate the longer list.

```
{'a':'donkey', 'b':'monkey', 'c':'whale', 'd':'dog'}
```

Then, you can access the values with the keys: `d['a']`